# Change the base of a laravel collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Is possibile to change the "base" of a `get` in Laravel?

To explain me, if I execute this:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
dd($books);
```

I will get something like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#903
     all: [
       App\Book {#932
         id: 1,
         name: "book1",
         author: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#939
           all: [
             App\Author{#945
               id: 1,
               name: "pippo"
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
    }
```

So the "base" is `Book`, I would like to have the base that is `Author`, like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#939
    all: [
        App\Author{#945
            id: 1,
            name: "pippo"
            },
        ],
    },
```

or this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#939
    all: [
        App\Author{#945
            id: 1,
            name: "pippo"
            book: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
                id: 1,
                name: "book1",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

Is it possible in some way?

P.S.: in my case I can't change the get method, so the first part

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')
```

cannot be changed

Comment: Do you mean you only want the "Author" part of the collection of books?

Comment: Nope, I would like to "extract" all Authors from the collection, so I can "navigate" to collection foreach Author

Comment: why can't you query from the author side and eager load their books?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need keyBy() eloquent function. Example:

```
$collection = collect([
        ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
        ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
    ]);

    $keyed = $collection->keyBy('product_id');

    $keyed->all();

    /*
        [
            'prod-100' => ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
            'prod-200' => ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
        ]
    */
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-keyby

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Many(Books) to One(Author) relationship, you could do

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
$author = $books->first()->author
```

Because you are returning a collection, you have to select one i.e `first()` and the get the author for that.

Also:

```
$author = App\Book::with('author')->where('field', 'condition', 'value')->first()->author;
```

If you want to get for all the books:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
$authors = [];
foreach($books as $book){
    $authors[] = $book->author;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform that collection and have it contain authors with the book.

```
$books = Book::with('author')->get();
$books->transform(function ($book) {
    return $book->author;
    }
);
dd($books);
```

This iterates through your collection and replaces every element with the result of the provided callback, which is the author in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't get the inverse: getting all the authors that have a book?

```
$authors = App\Author::whereHas('book')->get();
```